# What is happening with event handlers in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose we have

```
on("event", cb);
```

where `cb` is a callback function.

**Question:** I understand, conceptually, that what this is doing is saying "if the event named 'event' is triggered, execute the callback `cb`".  But what's going on in more precise JavaScript terms?  For example, what exactly is being **returned** by this this `on(..)` call?  What else is going on -- literally -- here that an intermediate developer should know about?

Comment: I'd suggest looking at an [implementation](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/events.js#L140) and tracking the process of registering and triggering events.

Comment: If calling `.on()` on an EventEmitter, it returns the EventEmitter. E.g. `stream.on('event', cb)` will return `stream` so you can chain calls.

Answer (score 0):

When you write on('event', cb) on your app, the event demultiplexer stores: operation, resource and handler (cb in this case). when the IO is finished, it goes to the event queue where the the event loop is iterating over and executing event's callbacks.